# Azure Table Storage sdk 1.6 Upsert not inserting

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-sdk-.net

I'm trying to use the new upsert feature of asure sdk 1.6 (against the storage emulator).

But I only managed to get the update working. When I try to upsert whit a new rowkey I get `resource not found` exception.

```
 var context = new TableServiceContext(_cloudStorageAccount.TableEndpoint.ToString(), _cloudStorageAccount.Credentials)
            {
                MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking,
                ResolveType = (unused) => typeof(SmartTableServiceEntity)
            };
context.AttachTo(tableName, smartEntity, "*");
            context.UpdateObject(smartEntity);
            context.SaveChangesWithRetries(SaveChangesOptions.ReplaceOnUpdate);
```

If I put `AddObject` it does the insert but not the update.
I was thinking being able to do both in one action thanks to the new sdk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up this a solution that seems to works on devstorage and on real storage

```
var context = CreateNewContext();

            context.IgnoreResourceNotFoundException = true;

            if (context.StorageCredentials.AccountName == "devstoreaccount1")
            {
                var entityCheck = context.CreateQuery<SmartTableServiceEntity>(tableName)
                    .Where(e => e.PartitionKey == partitionKey && e.RowKey == rowKey).FirstOrDefault();

                if (entityCheck == null) {
                    context.AddObject(tableName, smartEntity);
                }
                else  {
                    context.Detach(entityCheck);
                    context.AttachTo(tableName, smartEntity, "*");
                    context.UpdateObject(smartEntity);
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                context.AttachTo(tableName, smartEntity, null);
                context.UpdateObject(smartEntity);
            }
            context.SaveChangesWithRetries(SaveChangesOptions.ReplaceOnUpdate);
```

does someone has a better solution?
notice the difference bettween "*" and null is it ok?

thank you by advance

Comment: I wouldn't bother to workaround this limitation of local storage for two reasons: (1) Pricing at $0.14 per GB stored per month and $0.01 per 10,000 storage transactions (meaning that I would use a real Azure account); and (2) most probably the next release of Windows Azure Tools/SDK will have that feature for the local storage emulator.

Comment: Yes indeed that makes sens. Thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

it will only work against real Azure storage. Development storage does not support Upsert operation.
Also you must set the IgnoreResourceNotFoundException property of the tableServiceContext to true.

Comment: it is said here :) The new SDK which is on the corner might address this, but I am 100% sure.

Comment: FWIW it's also said [in the documentation for the Table Service API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh452242). When in doubt, always go back to the core REST API; the C# SDK is just a wrapper.

Comment: The documentation for the Table Service API no longer mentions this.  And in fact, InsertOrReplace operations will work under most conditions in the 4.0.0.0 version of the Azure Storage Emulator.  It will work with the development credentials and it will work with SAS credentials that allow access to the entire table.  But, as of the latest version today, it continues to return 404s if you try to use SAS credentials that specify a min and max partition key.  Source:  The last 10 hours of my life.

Answer (score 0):

When using the real Azure accounts, as well as setting the IgnoreResourceNotFoundException to true, it is also important to pass null for the eTag parameter, or use the overload that does not accept the eTag value. Otherwise you will get ResourceNotFound exceptions.